# Remove invalid, empty and untouched classes on select with an option dynamically selected

Tags: angularjs

I have this code:

HTML:

```
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-6">

                        <md-input-container>
                            <label>Country</label>
                            <md-select required ng-model="model.userCountry" id="res_country" name="res_country" ng-change="updateTimeZone(model.userCountry)" aria-label="select">
                                <md-option ng-repeat="country in country" value="{{country.gid}}"> {{country.name}} </md-option>
                            </md-select>
                        </md-input-container>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">

                        <md-input-container id="timezone">
                            <label>Timezone</label>
                            <md-select required ng-model="model.userZone" id="res_zone" name="res_zone" aria-label="select">
                                <md-option ng-repeat="zone in zone" value="{{zone.gid}}"> {{zone.name}} </md-option>
                            </md-select>
                        </md-input-container>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

In my controller functions I'm taking the list of timezones based on the country selected. When I select a country, if there is only 1 timezone, it gets selected by default.

My issue is that, when I load the view with a previously saved country and timezone, the timezone select has ng-empty and ng-invalid classes, and if I select the same option again, it gets marked as an error. Another case is when I select a country with 2 or more timezones and after that, select another country with only 1. The timezone will be selected, but also marked as an error. How can I remove those classes ?

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the required prop and added this instead:

```
ng-required="!model.userZone"
```

With this, the input would be marked as an error only if there's no selected value